# How can I make a numeric entry in Xamarin be right justified?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this:

```xml
 <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="100"/>
```

However the numbers are all left justified. Is there a way I can change this so the numbers are right justified and can I also change the text colors of the numbers that appear to blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Right-Justified Text

```xml
HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
```

## Blue Text

```xml
TextColor="Blue"
```

## Updated Code

```xml
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="Blue" />
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake. `HorizontalTextAlignment="End"` as described in [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/177585/#Comment_177585) comment